# Show warning message when enter wrong mobile no. format in Odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, validation, odoo, warnings, odoo-10

I have a integer field 'is_mobile'. Where user entering mobile. I want that when user enter wrong mobile no. format then it show warning message "invalid no. format" and also form not save without right format. For this i applied code, but it is not work as per requirement.

**Code is below:**

```
is_mobile = fields.Integer("Mobile")

@api.multi
    @api.constrains('is_mobile')
    def _check_phone_number(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.is_mobile and len(rec.is_mobile) != "^[0-9]{10}$" :
                raise ValidationError(_("Wrong value enter"))
            else:
                return False
        return {}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: self represent your mobile number : just check it with your regex expression you don't need to loop and certainly not to do both in the same time

Comment: I don't want to fix any number. I only want to apply validation on format(10 digits).

Comment: Why you use integer field in mobile no?You can use onchange

Comment: Do you have any example for new api?

Comment: here is the free app available for the mobile number validation https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/inputmask_widget/

Comment: but phone number should be a String not integer!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
@api.onchange('mobile')
def _onchange_mobile(self):
    if self.mobile:
        if re.match("^[0-9]\d{10}$", self.mobile) == None:
            raise ValidationError("Enter valid 10 digits Mobile number")
```

You can use **onchange** for this. don't forget to **import re**

Comment: It is shows following error "TypeError: expected string or buffer"

Comment: @PAWANSHARMA:change the type to char instead of integer

Comment: whay change the integer type just call built-in str to convert the mobile to a string:  `str(self.mobile)`

Comment: Ok, now i changed field type from integer to char, and it is show warning when no. is less then 10. but show "odoo server error" above 10 digits. I want that below and above 10 it show warning and form should not save. And only take integer value not character or any other else.

Comment: But `re.match("^[0-9]{10}$", self.mobile)` I think this is enough to check the length and the digits. What is wrong with it,  the use is not allowed to save phone number with other characters

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking of validation then no need to add method for that in py. Just add **type="tel"** in xml. Like this

```
<input type="tel" name="phone"/>
```

You can refer base code and you get idea what exactly I am talking about.

Comment: When using this, then my integer value is comma separated.That's not as per my requirement. I just want validation for mobile no.(10 digits) else show "invalid format'.

Comment: add size in field defination